# NEAR Locking Funds into smart contract

Tags: nearprotocol, near, assemblyscript, near-sdk-as

i'm quite struggling understanding how we can deposit and withdraw funds from smart contract on NEAR blockchain.

I'm currently using near-sdk-as with AssemblyScript. According to documentation I do have the
`ContractPromiseBatch.create(recipient).transfert(amount)`

But how can we lock funds into the smart contract and withdraw it from allowed accounts ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call your method with `--amount <some amount here>` you have deposited these amounts to your contract balance. For example:

```
near call  $CONTRACT add '{"url":"http://EXAPMLE.com", "title":"hello world"}' --accountId $AUTHOR --amount 3  //this is 3 NEARS you deposit to contract balance
```

When you want to send an amount from your contract balance to another person's balance you can use the `contractPromiseBatch` API as follows:

```
const toAnotherPerson = ContractPromiseBatch.create("anotherPerson.testnet");
toAnotherPerson.transfer(<some amount here>);
```